# Hotmail is sending Swedish characters ä, å and ö as E4, E5 and F6?

Tags: outlook.com

I've gotten complaints that the "Swedish characters" (ä, å, ö) are getting corrupted when I send e-mail through Hotmail. They show up as E4, E5 and F6 instead. The e-mail itself says charset=iso-8859-1. And my characters should work with that encoding.

Any ideas why my characters get messed up and how I can prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

> the "Swedish characters" (å, ä, ö) [..] show up as E4, E5 and F6 instead. The e-mail itself says charset=iso-8859-1.

The character set might very well be ISO 8859-1, still the email itself might be encoded as well. I guess you would find `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` in the source of message. And I expect you to see lots of equals-signs as well, like `=E4`, `=E5` and `=E6`, and equal-signs at the end of auto-wrapped lines?

In [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), E4 is indeed the hexadecimal value for ä, E5 is å and F6 is ö. In [quoted-printable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) those are encoded as `=E4`, `=E5` and `=E6`<sup>†</sup>. It seems that the email client of the recipient is not decoding properly. Hence:

- Do *all* recipients complain, or is it always the same few people?
- Can you [show us the source](https://superuser.com/questions/66082/why-do-russian-characters-in-some-received-emails-change-when-reading-in-david/66104#66104) of a very small test message?
- Can you configure Hotmail to always use Unicode (or UTF-8 encoding) instead?

  - [Apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#E-mail), Hotmail does support Unicode.
  - If there's no preference in Hotmail then Hotmail might be acting upon the encoding as received from the browser. Manually selecting the encoding of the Compose Message window [might help](http://www.vnisoft.com/english/UniHotmail.html) then. (But that would be a hack, really, as that encoding should affect *the viewing* of that compose window.)
  - Manually selecting the encoding might no longer be needed [since Live Hotmail](http://codeka.com/blogs/index.php/2006/01/25/hello_hotmail_1), *if* Live Hotmail indeed serves pages in UTF-8, and hence your browser *might* (I am not sure!) also send back data in UTF-8?
  - *Maybe* Hotmail is using different encodings for different browsers (like based on the order in the browser's `Accept-Charset` header), or even for different languages...?
  - Maybe using a single true Unicode character (what about [a Unicode smiley](https://superuser.com/questions/52671/how-do-i-create-unicode-smilies)?) while composing a message might make the browser send Unicode to the server, and make Hotmail encode the message in Unicode then?

---

<sup>†</sup> In UTF-8, ä, å and ö encode to hexadecimal C3A4, C3A5 and C3B6. These show as Ã¤, Ã¥ and Ã¶ when not decoded properly. Or, in quoted-printable this will be `=C3=A4`, `=C3=A5` and `=C3=B6`. So, using Unicode (more specifically: UTF-8) will *slightly* increase the length of the message, but might save you from trouble, especially when mixing with other Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

If it looks fine to you using characters with [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), but it doesn't on the recipient end, the [charset encodings](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) are not matching.

You might be using ISO-8859-1, but they could be viewing your email expecting UTF-8 encoding.

You'll need to have them line up, but you can't really be certain what the email client on the other end will use.

Try sending your emails out in UTF-8 format and see if that helps/cuts down the complaints.

If you're sending through the site, you won't be able to set the character encoding. But if you download Windows Live Mail, you can.

Go to:

> File > Tools > Options

(You may need to tap <kbd>Alt</kbd> to bring up the menu.)

The Options dialog will pop up.

[image: options in live mail]

Go to the Send tab and click **International Settings...**

From there you will be able to select the encoding on your sent emails.

Comment: I would love to send e-mail in utf-8. But I can't figure out how to do it with hotmail.

Comment: The other option, if using Hotmail, is to download the Live Mail program.